# Insufficient GPU RAM on Google Colab Pro+ with access to A100 GPU with 40GB RAM

Tags: gpu, out-of-memory, google-colaboratory

Currently on Colab Pro+ plan with access to A100 GPU w 40 GB RAM. However, my application using LLM still crashed because ran out of GPU RAM. Any way to increase the GPU RAM if only temporarily, or any programmatic solution to reduce dynamic GPU RAM usage during running?

Have tried to run TPU with 36 GB RAM (some documentation cited 100GB RAM available for TPU), but application still crashed because ran out of memory.